# Google Maps IOS SDK - Refreshing the MapView. (Objective-c)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, google-maps-sdk-ios

I made a settings tab for the MapView's ViewController and it works fine when I open the MapViews's VC the first time. but when I change the settings after I opened and loaded the mapView the first time the settings that I changed don't apply to the mapView because it did not refresh. Is there a way of refreshing the data of the mapView? I have searched everywhere and couldn't find an answer.

if this question have been answerd before can you link me to it? Thank you.

- I'm using the GoogleMaps ios sdk.
- and I'm using obj-c.

Comment: i didn't try anything because i dont know how to do it in the first place. what do you mean by "clear and add annotations" ?

Answer (score 1):

If your settings just changes the icons, annotations, map markers or layers color , or location of markers or layer, the simplest way to do is clear all the markers and layers you add on the map view and re-add them. For example, implement a `refreshMapView` method

```
-(void)refreshMapView
{
    [mapView clear];//this line clears all the markers or layers you drew on the mapView.
    // then implement your method to re-draw the markers and layers, or load new settings.
    // for example, go through your marker list, and add them as follows:
    for (id yourobject in yourMarkerArray){
        GMSMarker *marker = [GMSMarker markerWithPosition:coordinatesOfMarker];
        //custom marker here, set title, or snippets, or icon, etc...
        marker.map = mapView;
    }
    // you can also redraw any map overlay here...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Jing's answer to implement a `refreshMapView` method is good, you could call that in your map view controller's `viewWillAppear` section.

Make sure you're actually setting the `mapView` properties in the same scope — i.e., your settings view and your map view may be looking at a different object or changes may be getting discarded. Without seeing the code for how you're trying to modify those settings, it's difficult to say.